# Dropzone.js does not work because of htaccess URL rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, dropzone.js

My htaccess file is interfering with the implementation of Dropzone.js on my website. Here is the htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

#Force non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

Options -Indexes
```

Basically I am forcing a non-www redirect and am hiding the .php extension from the URL. However, I did not know that that would interfere with Dropzone.js, which requires a file name in the action attribute of the form or in the url property of the Dropzone object.

How can I hide the .php extension without interfering with Dropzone.js?

Comment: Could you please also post the HTML. Why don't you remove the .php from the URL there too?

Comment: Hi Enyo, thanks! I took out the .php from the action attribute last night and that didn't work, but I've done it again (after getting some sleep) and it does work now. Thanks again! I should really get some sleep next time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone! I took out the .php extension from the action attribute and like Enyo suggested that fixed it.